# Append cell range to end of different row based on column 1 values

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a student contact spreadsheet as shown below, where each students has 2, sometimes 3 parental contacts. As can be seen on `Sheet1`, each student's contact is on a separate row in the spreadsheet.

[image: Sheet1]

However, I need it to get it into the format on Sheet2, ie. where Column A values match, those rows are joined together.

[image: Sheet2]

The actual sheet has about 2000 records so manually going through and cutting and pasting isn;t really an option.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Dave.

Comment: How far have you gone? Show us your attempts so we can direct you to the right path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this needs to be a two-step process - see Sheet3 in this sheet: https://goo.gl/IS8lN6

The first formula in cell A2 creates a list of the IDs:

`=UNIQUE(Sheet1!A2:A)`

The second formula in cell B2 (and copied down the column) transfers the contact details from columns to rows:

`=SPLIT(CONCATENATE(FILTER(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(Sheet1!A:D),"n/a",Sheet1!A:D)&"|"),Sheet1!A:A=A2)),"|")`

You can also hide column A if you prefer

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks a lot for that, it works as expected. However, upon closer inspection of my actual parent spreadsheet, there are a lot of empty cells (eg, where a parent doesn't have an email address or occupation). This then means that column data is shifted and doesn't align in the results sheet - you can try this by deleting a cells contents in Sheet1. 

I could just do a find and replace and put N/A in these cells I guess, but is there any way that the formula can ignore or skip empty cells?

Comment: I've added IF and ISBLANK to replace the empty cells with "n/a":   =SPLIT(CONCATENATE(FILTER(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(Sheet1!A:D),"n/a",Sheet1!A:D)&"|"),Sheet1!A:A=A2)),"|")

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks a lot Chris!